# Default username and password of tomcat 7 in azure wbsites

Tags: tomcat, azure, azure-web-app-service

What is the Default username and password of tomcat 7 when we create azure website with tomcat 7 from gallery. i have tried admin,root, etc nit working :(

if there is no default username and password. is there any way to access the tomcat manager??
is there any way to access catalina config to change the user configration in azure websites??

please help.. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is no default user. You can define your a user in `manager-gui` role to be able to use it with `/manager/html` this definition goes into `wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\conf\tomcat-users.xml`

You can edit that file in FTP and add your user, but an easier way would be to go into `https://<YourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and log-in with your <strike>[deployment credentials](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials)</strike>     azure account and go to that file and edit it in the browser. You can also use Monoco (Visual Studio Online) `https://<YourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Dev` but you need to enable it in portal first, then use your deployment credentials again.

After you get to the XML, you need to add something like the following to your `<tomcat-users>` tag

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Please restart your website after the changes takes place.

Comment: You also need to restart your website after the changes.